# Why does Python's queue.get() function check if the queue is not empty inside a with block that acquires the not_empty lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, locking

I'm trying to better understand the queue library, so here's the code that's making me scratch my head:

```
def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        '''Remove and return an item from the queue.
        If optional args 'block' is true and 'timeout' is None (the default),
        block if necessary until an item is available. If 'timeout' is
        a non-negative number, it blocks at most 'timeout' seconds and raises
        the Empty exception if no item was available within that time.
        Otherwise ('block' is false), return an item if one is immediately
        available, else raise the Empty exception ('timeout' is ignored
        in that case).
        '''
        with self.not_empty: # <-------- notice this lock guarantees the queue is not empty
            if not block:
                if not self._qsize():
                    raise Empty
            elif timeout is None:
                while not self._qsize(): # <---------- so then why is this necessary?
                    self.not_empty.wait()
            elif timeout < 0:
                raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
            else:
                endtime = time() + timeout
                while not self._qsize():
                    remaining = endtime - time()
                    if remaining <= 0.0:
                        raise Empty
                    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
            item = self._get()
            self.not_full.notify()
            return item
```

As per my annotations above, I'm wondering why it's necessary to check if the queue is not empty, if we've already acquired the lock guaranteeing the queue is not empty? My understanding of the "with" statement is that it calls .acquire() on the lock self.not_empty, and .acquire() blocks until the lock is available. So shouldn't timeouts be handled there?

Comment: Acquiring the lock is different from `wait`ing on it.

Comment: Just guessing that `self.not_empty` is a `threading.Condition` object. If so, then it does not, in and of itself, tell you the truth of the condition. In this case, it does not tell you whether the queue is empty or not empty.  What it does is, it provides the means by which one thread can `wait()` for the condition to change, and another thread can `notify()` the first thread when it does change. But, to actually _know_ whether the condition is true or not, the waiter must look at some other variable or function— `self._qsize()` in this case.